# what is the correct and easy way for initialization of class containing array of tuples?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, initialization, tuples

I have a class which contains array of tuples like the following:

```
template<size_t __v, typename ... __tz>
class turray{
public:
    std::tuple<__tz ...> array[__v];
};
```

It does not have any user defined constructor and I was wondering how can I initialize it.
Please consider the following methods:

```
int main(){
    turray<2, int, float> mturray0{std::tuple<int, float>{1, 1.1}, std::tuple<int, float>{2, 2.2}}; //works but is very big
    turray<2, int, float> mturray1{{1, 1.1}, {2, 2.2}};// causes error
}
```

The first method works but is very big and not desired. the second method causes the following error:

```
error: too many initializers for ‘turray<2, int, float>’
  227 |  turray<2, int, float> mturray1{{1, 1.1}, {2, 2.2}};
      |                                                   ^
```

I would appreciate it if some one could show me what should be the correct method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add another pair of braces:

```
turray<2, int, float> mturray1 { { {1, 1.1}, {2, 2.2} } };
//                                 ^      ^                tuple
//                               ^                    ^    array
//                             ^                        ^  turray
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/corPTK).

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain

Comment: @AKL Does the edit help? I'm not sure what you thought each of the braces meant in your snippet.